# Delegate control in master page applies to sub sites which are not using same master page

Tags: 2010, master-page, navigation, delegate-control

I have created a master page in which I have used delegate control to add custom navigation. On the parent site, everything is working fine.

But when I am creating a new subsite, by default that subsite is using V4.master master page. But still, my delegate control is visible in that site.

Can anyone suggest how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to change the scope of the feature activating the delegate control from site to web, so that only applies to the current web rather than the entire site collection.

I am bit confused that you wrote you have added the control in your custom master. From what I remember do delegate control apply to the respective placeholder and are activated by a feature. If this does not help please post more details on what you are doing.